# SharedPreferences variable always returns false

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using a Preference Fragments following the step by step guide on [Android guide](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Fragment).

I am trying to set some preferences using this fragment, so later on the code I can check the value of each variable to perform actions accordingle.

Mi Preference fragment is working fine. However, when I try to recover the value of a CheckedBoxPreference somewhere else on the code, it always returns false.

This is the preference xml file :

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:persistent="true"
    >
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="NOTIFICACIONES"
        android:key="pref_key_storage_settings">

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="sendMail"
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:persistent="true"
        android:summary="Send emails to contacts"
        android:title="E-mail"/>
</PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

This is the class I've done to use SharedPReferences

```
public class Prefs{
    private static Prefs myPreference;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private static final String NOMBRE_PREFERENCIAS = "MisPreferencias";

    public static Prefs getInstance(Context context) {
        if (myPreference == null) {
            myPreference = new Prefs(context);
        }
        return myPreference;
    }

    private Prefs(Context context) {

        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(NOMBRE_PREFERENCIAS,context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

 public Boolean getBoolean(String key)
    {
        boolean returned = false;

        if (sharedPreferences!= null) {
            returned = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key,false);
        }

        return returned;
    }
}
```

And this is how I check if the options is selected, so I can send/or not emails to clients

```
Prefs preferences = Prefs.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        if(preferences.getBoolean("sendMail")
        {
          // .... send email   
        }
```

As I said, what is strange is that It is persistent on the settings fragment ( if I select the option sendEmmail, it is selected even if I close the app and reopen it. However, when I check the value using my method, it always returns false.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Propably you didn't saved properly a value, did you used `value.commit();` or `value.apply();` method at the end of your saving method? I don't see a code of saving, please add it

Comment: I didn't code anything because it is supposed to change the value automatically when I change the state of the checkedPreference. Am I wrong? As I said, it seems that is storing the value because I am able to see the state every time I enter on my preferenceFragment and the checked state change accordingly, even if I close and restart the app. However, I can't retrieve the value manually usign the code above. That is what I don't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using the preference fragment, you should be using [`PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context)) to retrieve your preferences. You're using named preferences at the moment.

From [developer.android.com on PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html):

> Shows a hierarchy of Preference objects as lists. These preferences
>   will automatically save to SharedPreferences as the user interacts
>   with them. To retrieve an instance of SharedPreferences that the
>   preference hierarchy in this fragment will use, call
>   getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context) with a context in
>   the same package as this fragment.

So the line

```
sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(NOMBRE_PREFERENCIAS,context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

should be replaced with:

```
sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```